# HTTP Client Request for an AWS API Gateway

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, http

I have an angular frontend using typescript and I am trying to make a http request to a AWS API-Gateway. Now the problem is, I need to write the following javascript code as typescript code and send a http request but I do not know how.

The Request to the AWS API gateway needs an AWS Cognito jwtToken (in this case its "accessToken"). I also need to pass the "type", which is the name of the function to be executed on the API (in this case 'POST'). I also need to pass a string which chooses what data I receive.

```
Auth.currentSession().then(tok => {
      const accessToken = tok.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      console.log('from floorview: ' + accessToken);

      function requestItem(source) {

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'https://XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prop/dashboard',
          headers: {
            Authorization: accessToken
          },
          data: JSON.stringify({
            Source: source.toString(),
            tableName: 'h16b-testset',
            operation: 'read'
          }),
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          success: completeRequest,
          error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('Error requesting ride: ', textStatus, ', Details: ', errorThrown);
            console.error('Response: ', jqXHR.responseText);
            alert('An error occured when requesting your unicorn:\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
          }
        }).then(r => console.log(r));
      }

      requestItem(996);

      function completeRequest(result) {
        console.log('Response received from API: ', result);
      }

    });
  }
```

Now my problem is, how do I write this javascript code as typescript code while using angulars HTTPClient. If there is another method then please tell me. I always get 401s or 403s when I try to run this code using an HTTPClient.

```
Auth.currentSession().then(tok => {
      const accessToken = tok.getAccessToken();
      const jwt = accessToken.getJwtToken();

      this.authKey = jwt;


      const params = new HttpParams().set('Source', '996');
      params.append('tableName', 'h16b-testset');
      params.append('operation', 'read');
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.authKey);
      headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');

      this.http.request(
        'POST',
        'https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prop/dashboard',
        {
          headers,

          responseType: 'json'
        }
      ).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log('hallo' + res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('error occured with httpclient: ' + err.message);
        }
      );
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the correct authorization headers? You can inspect it in your network inspector in chrome. Can we also see your HttpClient implementation of this request?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request... Please post the TypeScript code that you have already tried.

Comment: added my http request. I need to send the source number with the request as well, but params just appends it to the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like the following (using `concatMap` operator):

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    from(Auth.currentSession())
    .pipe(concatMap(tok => this.requestItem(tok, 996)))
    .subscribe(
        result => console.log('Response received from API: ', result),
        err => {
          console.log('error occured with httpclient: ' + err.message);
        }
     );
  }

  requestItem(token, source) : Observable<any> {
    this.http.post(url, {
            Source: source.toString(),
            tableName: 'h16b-testset',
            operation: 'read'
          }, 
         headers,
         params
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your http client as:

```js
    this.http.post(
          'https://XXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prop/dashboard',
          {
            Source: '<id>',
            tableName: 'h16b-testset',
            operation: 'read'
          },
          {
              headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': '<token>'})
          }
    ).subscribe(res=> console.log(res), failure => console.error(failure))
```

This way you will send source in body of request and with authorization token in header.

For more info about `HttpClient` please see https://angular.io/guide/http.

Comment: I am still getting a missing authentication token error.

Comment: Did you can see header in network inspector? Did you replaced `<token>` with your actual authorization token?

Comment: yes, it says "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type" but it still gives me a http failure response 0 unknown error, and then it says missing authentication token. I am most definitely giving it the jwtToken it needs for Cognito authentication